# Tsql IF statement is not being evaluated correctly

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, ssis-2012

An xml file gets parsed and populates 7 tables within a stored procedure in an SSIS package.
When I pass an empty xml file one of the tables (Eg Table7) was still getting populated.

As a workaround to prevent it, I added an IF statement. When I run my procedure in SSMS I get the desired results as the @RecCt =0. All inserts are bypassed.
But when I execute the SSIS package, only ‘Table7’ gets populated (This table has summary values).

```
Create procedure SP_test
As
Begin
    Declare @RecCt int
    select @RecCt=(select count(*) from dbo.Order)
    If @RecCt >0
    Begin
        Insert into Table1 …      
        Insert into Table2 …
        Insert into Table3 …
        Insert into Table4 …      
        Insert into Table5 …
        Insert into Table6 …      
        Insert into Table7 …    
    End
    Else
    Begin
        Select ‘Empty File’
    End
End
```

Why is this happening in spite of being evaluated as false?    Thank you much.  SD

Comment: Aside: You can use `select @RecCt = Count(*) from dbo.Order;` rather than two selects.

Comment: You mean that although `@RecCt=0`, `Table7`gets populated? If you instead ment `RecCt>0`then you should check the dots behind the other 6 table names.

Comment: Side note: You should avoid using the `sp` prefix for stored procedures. Microsoft has reserved that prefix for system procedures. Use `stp` or no prefix at all.